# Anionic Ring Opening Polymerisation

Tags: polymers

[image]

I figure that t-BuLi has effectively a negative charge on the carbon that is attached to 3 methyl groups. So I'm wondering what is the accurate way to represent this reaction, does the carbon anion attack a silicon atom in the chain like so-
[image]

Comment: Pretty much this. tBu- is a poor nucleophile but when there is no other pathway...